# Asynchronous version of window.onbeforeunload()

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, asynchronous

The window.onbeforeunload() function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

is there a way to use this function asynchronously, so that I can pass it a callback - for example - I am using Backbone and I would like to save all my front-end collections before the user has a chance to close the window.

so that would look something like:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(callback) {
  Object.keys(collections).forEach(coll){
       coll.persist();
    }
   callback(null, 'Dialog text here.');
};
```

(this isn't perfect, we might use the async library to ensure all collections get saved, but it's close enough for now).

Comment: You'd probably be better off pro-actively saving the changes as they change on the front-end, rather than try to do it in the `onbeforeunload` event (which is unreliable at times)

Comment: ...and if you're concerned about proactively saving settings that shouldn't be changed immediately but rather on an actual "save" command, save them proactively but as a draft object/document/whatever.